# Which MUA allow mark mail thead that I started or reply to?

Tags: email, usability, thunderbird

Which MUA allow mark mail thead that I started or repaly to?

This allow focus my attention firstly on this thread.

Also it is good to be notified somehow if this event happen.

I currently use Thunderbird but can not find in its docs or in google answer for this question.

Comment: Why this is offtopic? According to FAQ "software tools commonly used by programmers". Do you not use mail reader? Good mail reader allow more effective read *tech* news/mail lists and save your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[claws mail](http://www.claws-mail.org/) allows you to watch / ignore threads